Encrypt JPEG with `openssl` Command Line Utilities then preview randomized set of pixels
I am trying to preview an encrypted JPEG with randomized set of pixels got inspired by this

download the test image
wget -O i.jpg https://i.ibb.co/M8nJ9cF/i.jpg


encode the jpg file using 256-bit AES in CBC mode
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in i.jpg -out o.jpg -pass pass:123


copy header from original to encrypted (JPEG hasn't 54-byte header maybe here is the issue but tried with 2-byte with no luck)
dd if=i.jpg of=o.jpg bs=54 count=1 conv=notrunc



afterwards I open the encrypted file but I get this error
The file "o.jpg" could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn't recognise.

by the way I can successfully decrypt
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in o.jpg -out i.jpg -pass pass:123

Environment

sw_vers macOS 14.4.1 (23E224) x86_64
openssl -v OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024)


This approach won't work with JPEG. This isn't to say that JPEG is safe to encrypt with ECB. It's just that JPEG doesn't demonstrate the issue so obviously to the human eye. Compressed formats have more complex structure, and the result of encrypting them does not map directly to the original structure.
You need to work with an uncompressed format. Typically this example is done with BMP. Uncompressed formats generally have an equivalent structure in their plain and encrypted forms. For an example, see https://github.com/tkeliris/ecb-penguin.

thanks to point such but I asked for openssl Command Line Utilities approach

@Ax: the picture in the example you link is named pic_original.bmp but it is actually JPEG, and doesn't work with the encryption operations shown. Probably the blogger actually had BMP on their own computer, but when they posted it the blog software optimized it because serving huge BMPs over the internet reduces the value of the blog. On Windows if I use MSPaint to save it as 256-color BMP, your openssl+dd process works; I assume there is some equivalent tool on MacOS but I don't know what. But this is not programming or development.

hi @dave_thompson_085 I asked help to find the commands by using openssl Command Line Utilities to encrypt JPEG and then preview the randomized set of pixels. Linux commands with some adjustments are fine on MacOS too

The example demonstration you're trying to achieve is not possible with JPEG. There are no OpenSSL or other tools that can do this. It's not how JPEG works. The demonstration only works in this highly visual way for uncompressed bitmap formats.
